# How to print JavaScript new Date() in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime

I cannot print simple JavaScript dates inside of React.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './ActivityWarningText.css';

class ActivityWarningText extends Component {

        render() {
            const str = new Date();
            return(
          <div>
            <h1>All activity is recorded. {str}</h1>
          </div>
         )
        }

}

export default ActivityWarningText;
```

I get this error:

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Apr 25 2018 18:09:03 GMT+0400 (Arabian Standard Time)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in h1 (at index.js:17)
    in div (at index.js:16)
    in ActivityWarningText (at index.js:34)
    in component (created by Route)
    in Route (at index.js:34)
    in div (at index.js:33)
    in div (at index.js:30)
    in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
    in BrowserRouter (at index.js:29)
    in App (at withAuthentication.js:36)
    in WithAuthentication (at index.js:14)
```

This works however, `str.getFullYear()`

Comment: The error tells you everything you need to know. `{str}` is not valid if `str` is an object. It needs to be a string. `Date` provides many functions that convert to string, such as `date.toISOString()` or `date.toDateString();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Date` object has to be casted to string. You can try with

```
{str.toString()}
```

or

```
{`${str}`}
```

Comment: Can this be done with every object? Even objects with child arrays like JSON?

Comment: It can be applied to anything that has `toString` in its interface, so yes.

Answer (score 2):

`new Date();` gives you an Object. You can't render Objects as children in React. You can get a stringified version of the date with `toString()`.

Answer (score 1):

Objects can't be injected as children in react components.
You can use the date.toISOString() function that would convert the date object into a thing that can be rendered as children to a react component.